# Is a cooling fan necessary for a laptop similar to the ASUS K73E?

Tags: laptop, cooling

Is a cooling fan necessary for a laptop similar to the [ASUS K73E](http://www.asus.com/Notebooks/Versatile_Performance/K73E/#features)?

I'm not entirely sure about this. After working with one the other day for a client, it seemed like it was running pretty cool, but I'm not sure if the computer was actually running cool or if it had more to do with IceCool Technology feature that keeps the mouse and palm rest area cool.

The bottom of the laptop didn't seem very warm either - does anyone have any experience with the [ASUS K73E](http://www.asus.com/Notebooks/Versatile_Performance/K73E/#features) where the thing burned up with normal usage?

Comment: You could skip the two identical, misguidingly labeled links to the same web shop to make this post look less spammy.

Comment: Sorry...posted the wrong link... :-p

Comment: Okay link changed.  Keep Calm and carry on, nothing to see here folks...

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an identical system, but i *do* have another 2nd generation core i5 system. They run significantly cooler than the core 2 duo i had before, and i have on occasion, run it on my lap without significant discomfort.

I would say its not necessary, though some cooling pads *do* angle the system to a more comfortable level.

Comment: Well I'm not worried about lap burns, so much as I'm worried about the processor frying itself when it gets too hot.  But yeah I'm glad to hear the i5 runs at a lower temperature than earlier models.

Comment: In most cases aren't you able to set a failsafe temperature in the BIOS at which the system just powers off if the temperature gets too high?

Comment: in theory, yes, and most modern processors thermal throttle should they hit dangerous temperatures. I've never come close tho. I run fairly close to ambient temperatures most of the time

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna say it's probably not necessary.  The manufacturers build them with enough cooling to keep them from being damaged.

They could get uncomfortable to the touch in some situations, but not hot enough to destroy itself unless something is going wrong.

Comment: Well I just wondered if in the past 2 years or so they've been cooling them down a bit, since the past couple of people's laptops I've setup have all been that way.

Comment: The built in cooling should be suffecient, but I've noticed that outside the business word the cooling pads are a popular choice. The place I work deploys about 150 laptops a month to employees and none of them are given the cooling pads, as long as the vents are kept clear you should be fine without it.